# How can I get the <span> elements which have a specific class name in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, class

Using jQuery 1.9.1 and HTML5, I want to capture the elements which have only specific class names.

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<div>
     <span class="req">A</span>
     <span class="req notreq">B</span>
     <span class="req notreq">C</span>
     <span class="req">D</span>
</div>
```

I want to capture only the `<span>` elements with class `req` i.e. the values A and D.

Using jQuery, I can capture all the values using `console.log($('.req'));` and all the `notreq` values using `console.log($('span.req.notreq'))`

I need only `req` values. Any help?

Comment: $('span.req:not(.notreq)');

Comment: @spyder are you wanting ONLY the spans that have class `req` and that do NOT have class `notreq` which means you are wanting the A and D values?

Comment: Or do you mean that you want elements with only the class `rec`, without any other class names in there?  (Not necessarily `notreq`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the class name into the selector like this...

```
$("span[class='req']");
```

That will just return the span elements with only `req` as a class.

Comment: can i add more classes like $("span[class='req anotherreq']");

Comment: It will look for the exact string, rather than a list of multiple classes.  For that example to work it would have to be `<span class="req anotherreq"></span>`, but not `<span class="anotherreq req"></span>`.  It's checking for "class name equals"

Comment: I'm more than happy to admit you are right but the OP still hasn't really clarified his actual question and downvoting me for an ambiguous question isn't very cool!

Comment: now can i append a class name to these elements? say i want to add "muchreq" to the found elements. the output should be <span class="req much req">...</span> for each of these elements

Comment: Sorry @lucuma - we'll have to agree to disagree as the question seems 100% clear to me so you're answer, in my mind, is wrong.

Comment: 100% clear when 66% of the answers misunderstood?  That's fine we can agree to disagree and you obviously were the correct one though I think it would be helpful if you edited the question so it was clearer.

Comment: @lucuma *"the question seems 100% clear **to me**"*  Please stop taking it personally.  If it hurts you that much then you're on the wrong site :)

Comment: I've already said that it's perfectly clear to me.  If you want to edit it then that's your call, not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.req').not('.notreq').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: That doesn't return the ones that only have req.  It returns the ones that do not have notreq.  That's not what the question is.

Comment: Yes.  Are you not?  From the question - *"i want to capture the elements which have only specific class names."*

Comment: I understand what you're saying - the example was not needed.  What I am saying is that you have misunderstood the question and worked on purely the example code given.  See this modified example... http://jsfiddle.net/G9erN/1/

Comment: This is in the question:  Now i want to capture only the elements with class req, i.e the values A and D....  but i need only req values.  Perhaps the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Like I said you've misunderstood the question.  See my previous comment with modified fiddle.

Comment: I'd prefer that the OP clarify and tell me that instead of making an assumption. I've asked for clarification so let's see what he/she says

Answer (score 0):

Use the :not pseudo-element:

```
$('span.req:not(.notreq)');
```

Comment: That doesn't return the ones that only have req.  It returns the ones that do not have notreq.  That's not what the question is.